# Hello i am confused with this quadratic question.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why is it that when we look at equation for example $(x-2)^2+5$ and the question states "state the minimum point" the minimum point is $5$.

I get that the coordinates of minimum point is $(2,5)$ but why is only $y$ taken into consideration. Also if there is equation like $2(x-2)^2+5$ would the minimum point still be $(2,5)$?

please can you reply back to me as soon as possible as my exam is in few days and I really want to understand maths rather than "memorise it".

Comment: "The minimum point is 5" is sloppy. You could properly say find the minimum value of the expression $(x-2)^2+5$. On your 2nd question, yes the minimum value of the 2nd expression is also 5 and it alsol occurs at $x=2$.

Comment: Here is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for properly displaying functions.

Comment: Yes thankyou you made question 2 clearer for me but for first question the question that i was trying to get across was why is it that when we look at minimum value we only consider the y coordinate and not the x?

Comment: y is considered to be dependent upon x.  Or "y is a function of x".  More accurately we could write $f(x) = (x -2)^2 + 5$ rather than $y = (x-2)^2+5$.  So to find minimum value it is "understood" we mean "minimum value of the y output to what x input".

Comment: Question 2:  yessssss......  +5 shifts everything horizontally equally.  So the min/max of "goo" + 5 will be the same as the min/max of "goo".    So 2x"foo" simply stretches everything horizontally with the same orientation. max/min bx"foo" if b is positive will have the same max/min point as "foo" so $2(x - 2)^2+5$, $2(x-2)^2$,$(x-2)^2 + 5$ and $(x-2)^2$ will all achieve their minimums at the same x point.  As $(x-2)^2 \ge 0$ that min point will be with $(x-2)^2 = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

I'll just state what you've found already in more specific terms.

Given $$y(x) = (x-2)^2 + 5$$

you've found (correctly) that the minimum point is $(2,5)$.

The minimum *value* of the function is $y(2) = 5$.  The value of $x$ at which the minimum value of the function occurs is $x=2$.

(Nitpick:  $(x-2)^2 + 5$ is an expression, not an equation.  An equation needs an equals sign.)

To your other question, yes, the minimum of

$$y'(x) = 2(x-2)^2 + 5$$

still lies at $(2,5)$.  The term $2(x-2)^2$ is least when $x=2$.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback back everyone i will have fun reading it and prepare for my exams.

Answer (score 0):

The term $(x-2)^2+5$ has to be minimized. $5$ is a constant and cannot be influenced by a appropiate choice of $x$. And $(x-2)^2$ is greater or equal to $0$, because it is the square of $x-2$. The minimum of $(x-2)^2$ is if $x-2=0$- Therefore $y=0+5=5$ is the y-value of the minimum. But you also have to calculate the x-coordinate of the minimum. This is $x=2$ due the equation $x-2=0$.

In general $a(x-d)^2+e$  is the vertex form of the quadratic function. In your case $a=1$ is positive. Therefore the parabola is open above. Consequently the vertex is the minimum of the parabola. And the values of the coordinates are $(d,e)=(2,5)$.